# MissingMethodException after upgrading to ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I tried to upgrade to .NET Core 2.0 but after changing the SDK for every project I get the following exception when trying to start the application

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ISession.CommitAsync()'.
```

I tried to install the nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features in which the missing method is, but it did not help. When trying to access the method from my C# code the intelli sense is showing it like expected.

Comment: Are you sure the dll from the nuget package is in the bin folder, where it can be found at runtime?

Comment: delete bin folder and rebuild

Comment: When publishing the .dll is there (version is correct too). I already tried deleting the bin folder, clearing the nuget cache, restarting computer. Nothing helped :/

Comment: Share your csproj file?

Comment: Did you clear out the publish directory before publishing the version of the application built with ASP.NET Core 2.0? I had this exact issue when I upgraded to ASP.NET Core 2.0 Preview 1

Comment: I got it to work, see my answer below ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. We had a nuget package from ourself which had a reference to the old version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features. After upgrading our own nuget package it worked.